# Creating a GenericaDAO in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create a GenericDAO to handle with my entities and everything is alright except the update method it does not update the entity and there's no exception.

How could I fix it ?

trying

**GenericDAO**

```
public class GenericDAO<T> : IPersist<T> where T : class {
    private DatabaseContext context;

    public GenericDAO() {
        context = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public Boolean insert(T obj) {
        try{
            context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("Insert error: " + e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return false;        
    }


    public Boolean update(T obj) {
        try{
            context.Entry<T>(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;            
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("Update error: " + e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }


    public Boolean delete(T obj) {
        try{
            context.Set<T>().Remove(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("Delete error: " + e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T findObject(long id) {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll(){
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }   
}
```

**ProdutoDAO**

```
class ProdutoDAO : GenericDAO<Produto>{}
```

**Using**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO();

            Produto p = dao.findObject(1); //get the object
            p.descricao = "Bottle Water";
            p.dtCad = DateTime.Now;
            p.valor = 1.00m;

            //update object
            if (dao.update(p))            {
                Console.WriteLine("update ok!");
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("update error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: OMG @Jasen you alright, I forget to make the `SaveChanges()` I'm big stupid ..hhahaha... Now it works :D